# Why does List(T).Contains fail to find matches on lists of Entity Framework objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

I've got two lists of "Customer" objects, generated from Entity Framework. I need to compare the two lists to see if there are any differences between them so, naturally, I wrote something like this:

```
    private static List<Customer> originalList;

    public static bool TestForEQ(List<Customer> source, List<Customer> destination)
    {

      foreach(Customer cust in originalList) {
        if( !currentList.Contains(cust) )
        {
             return false;
        }
    }

 public static void CheckData()
 {
    var ctx = new CustomersEntities();

     if(originalList == null)
     {
         originalList = ctx.Customers.ToList<Customer>();
     }
     else
     {
        bool equiv = testForEQ(originalList, ctx.Customers.ToList<Customer>());
        originalList = ctx.Customers.ToList<Customer>()
     } 
 }
```

CheckData is called periodically from a Thread.

So when I stepped through it for the first time, before making any changes to the database between when originalList and currentList were generated, I was surprised to find that the two initial objects in the list were not - according to Contains() - equivalent and that the above code returned false.

I have verified that the basic properties of the two objects (Id, name etc) are equivalent and that no pair of objects from either list are treated as equivalent by Contains(), so ..

1) Can anyone help me find out what property(ies) of two apparently identical data objects are causing Contains() to fail on?

2) Does anyone know of anything on entity framework which would cause two generated entities to not be equivalent if fetched from an untouched data table at different times? Is there a timestamp of some sort? Or are they treated as references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, by default, you're checking reference equality...and that is failing.

To be sure you get the results you expect, you can create a custom comparer (by implementing [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)) and provide that to the `Contains()` method.

For example, the following implementation would compare Customers based on their Id:

```
public class CustomerEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Customer>
{
    public bool Equals(Customer c1, Customer c2)
    {
        return c1.Id == c2.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Customer c)
    {
        return c.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you could call Contains with:

```
if(!currentList.Contains(cust, new CustomerEqualityComparer())
    return false;
```

Comment: +1 The EF Code Generator doesn't override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for you, you can either implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>` or add new implementations of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in the `partial` class.

Comment: IMO, even better for ad hoc scenarios is to just use `Any()` from LINQ. `if(!currentList.Any(c => c.Id == cust.Id))`, and just place your notion of equality in the lambda.

Comment: @Matt Greer the problem with using .Any() like that is you end up with your "notion of equality" coded all over your app, rather than in one place.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The use of Comparer works fine, thanks, but I'd be curious to know which is the "better" method. Using LINQ seems more readable but, I suspect, less efficient.

Comment: @Matt - If you're not going to re-use the comparer for any other comparisons...the LINQ Any method would be fine. If you're going to re-use the same logic in multiple locations (which I typically find that I need to do whether I think I will up front or not), then use the comparer.

Comment: Absolutely, which is why I said 'ad hoc'. If equality is a common issue in your app, this is not the way to go.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like I ticked this too soon .. it's still failing. I suspect the problem might be that I'm comparing object to object ... so my comparer is literally checking c1 == c2 rather than an individual properly. But that's ideally what I need it to do .. is that wrong?

Comment: @Matt - Yes. That's wrong. That would still do the same comparison as it was doing before. The purpose of the EqualityComparer is to tell what properties of the Customer should be compared and how the comparison should be done (which is why I showed an example with Id which is typically how you uniquely identify something).

Comment: Hmm, okay. Is there no way to accomplish what I'm trying to do then? Ideally I need to check if *every* property is identical .. and this being entity framework many of the "properties" are in fact objects in themselves with their own properties and so on .. so any method of trying to directly compare them all is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: @Matt - The other option is to override Equals and GetHashCode in the Entity Framework generated partial classes (in different files, of course). Either way, you're going to have to do quite a bit of work to get things to work as desired.

Comment: OK, thanks for the pointer. Your help is very much appreciated.